# How do I clean up categories and tags for transactions in Quicken?

Tags: budget, software, quicken

After a few weekends of trying to get all of my transactions categorized and tagged, sometimes doing it in a rush, I'm left with a bunch of categories with duplicate meanings, and similarly redundant tags.

How do I get these organized again for purposes of budgeting?

Answer (score 2):

There are tools in Quicken which will let you delete a category and replace all references to it with another category. They aren't hard to find in the help, if I remember correctly.